# NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken DocumentToken

Tags: angular

I'm settings up a common library for all my Angular 5 projects. Library is a clone of GitHub repository [angular-library-starter-kit](https://github.com/zurfyx/angular-library-starter-kit).

Everything works fine until I try to use `HttpClientModule` (successor to `HttpModule`).

Here are contents of my `library.module.ts` file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MyService } from './my-service';

export * from './my-service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
  declarations: [
  ],
  providers: [
      MyService
  ],
})
export class LibraryModule { }
```

And here are contents of `my-service.ts` (which is **THE ONLY FILE** in the library):

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
        //
    }

    getData(): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient.get<any>('test.json');
    }

}
```

The library builds without any errors but when I try to use it in fresh Angular 5 app (`ng new myApp`) it gives an error:

```
AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HttpXsrfTokenExtractor -> InjectionToken DocumentToken]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HttpXsrfTokenExtractor -> InjectionToken DocumentToken]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken DocumentToken!
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:994)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1292)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1234)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1102)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1292)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1234)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1102)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10847)
    at _createClass (core.js:10888)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:10858)
```

I've even tried importing modules `HttpModule` and `HttpClientModule` in the Angular 5 app but I got the same error.

I've also tried removing `HttpModule` from both the app and library but still the same error.

<strike>The reason I'm using both `HttpModule` and `HttpClientModule` is because [apparently](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20101#issuecomment-341404350) `HttpClientModule` still depends on `HttpModule` to work.</strike> **I learned that this is not true.**

How can I resolve this?

**Note:** The fresh app works just fine with `ng serve` until I add `LibraryModule` to its `imports`.

Comment: Why import from my-service only to export immediately after?

Comment: @rrd Because if I don't export it I get `Module: 'library' has no exported member 'MyService'`. What do you recommend? I'd like everything that's public in my library to be importable from a single file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I poorly read the [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20101). Apparently when working with local libraries you have to add `--preserve-symlinks` argument to `ng serve`.

```
ng serve --preserve-symlinks
```

Also there is no need to import `HttpModule` anywhere and no need to import `HttpClientModule` inside the app if only the library depends on it.

Comment: Thank you! You saved me from jumping off the Golden Gate Bridge.  This should be documented better on Angular's part.

Answer (score 4):

Update to **Eric's** answer:

Since Angular/Cli v6 `--preserve-symlinks` argument has been removed. To add it, edit `angular.json` file accordingly:

```
[...]  
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "progress": true,
        "extractCss": false,
        "outputPath": "dist/xcs-web-ui",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "preserveSymlinks": true,
[...]
```