# InjectionToken DocumentToken! - DOTNET CLI

Tags: .net, angular, httpclient

I am using Dotnet CLI with Angular Template and to run the app I have to execute dotnet run so *--preserve-symlinks* doesn't work with dotnet.

I have the same issue when I am trying to execute the method POST of HttpClient throws *"No provider for InjectionToken DocumentToken!"*. I tried everything and I can't achieve it.

I tried with **Http** from *"@angular/http"* and it works but **HttpClient** doesn't work.

Someone can help me?

I want to use **HttpClient** because **HttpInterceptor**. Everything related to imports and dependency injection is Ok.

Similar post: [NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken DocumentToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48380173/nullinjectorerror-no-provider-for-injectiontoken-documenttoken)

Comment: You need to use HttpClient from `@angular/common/http`

Comment: Yes I know that.. but that was not the error. Finally I fixed.

Comment: Sorry I was just making sure

Comment: Don't worry, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed. The problem was dependencies. The actual version of DOTNET installs dependencies of Angular 4.2.5 and I have to upgrade 4.4.6 and it worked.

Just for you information, my attempts were with the latest version of angular too, but that dependencies didn't work, they caused errors with the compiler.

```
"@angular/animations": "4.4.6",
"@angular/common": "4.4.6",
"@angular/compiler": "4.4.6",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.6",
"@angular/core": "4.4.6",
"@angular/forms": "4.4.6",
"@angular/http": "4.4.6",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.6",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.6",
"@angular/platform-server": "4.4.6",
"@angular/router": "4.4.6",
```